# mysql - rollback script executed from terminal

Tags: mysql

I have a script that starts with "START TRANSACTION", alters tables, inserts in others, and ends with "COMMIT"

However, I am executing this script using:

```
mysql -u root --password="jajaja" my_schema < ./my_script.sql
```

The problem is that if there is an error in any line mysql exits and the transaction is not rollback. If I use --force then the execution continues to the "COMMIT" but it did not rollback on error.

How can I tell mysql to perform a rollback if an error happened while executing my script?

Comment: The `mysql` command-line client is supposed to rollback if it exits without committing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121917/automatic-rollback-if-commit-transaction-is-not-reached

Comment: `mysql --init-command=BEGIN -u root ...`

Comment: Unless you are using MySQL 8.0, `ALTER` terminates any open transactions.